# Way to stop windows explorer from prepending http to unknown names in address bar?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, address-bar

Is there a way to stop my Windows Explorer from launching the browser when typing an unknown name into the address bar?

It seems that the default behaviour is to prepend "http://" to any name not a valid path or an (indexed) file or folder name.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of that question, *that one is a duplicate of this one*. Just look at the time-stamps. Moreover, that question did not get an answer, so it is **not** a better go-to for this question. The accepted answer is only applicable (as a kludgy work-around no-less) to that OP’s specific use-case scenario. If anything, that question misleads people and eschews finding a solution to the actual problem.

Comment: Genuinely hope more people see this annoyance in Windows too. It's beyond infuriating when it triggers starting up my browser that has hundreds of tabs open. Like who even uses the file explorer to search the web, it's not saving any time.