# Disable opening browser from Windows Explorer Address Bar

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

**How can i prevent Windows explorer from opening my internet browser when I mistype something in the address bar?**

For example, I often type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, `cmd` to quickly select the address bar and open cmd.exe in the current directory.

However, I often mistype, and hit `cdm` instead of `cmd`.  This will open my default browser and search for cdm, and I deeply hate this.  Sure, it only takes a couple seconds to go back, but that doesn't keep me from hating it.

I'm not interested in making links of my commonly mis-typed programs (which I have actually done already), e.g. create a link of cdm.exe that points to cmd.exe.  I just want to turn this feature off, if possible.

Comment: Duplicate: [Way to stop windows explorer from prepending http to unknown names in address bar?](http://superuser.com/questions/234924/way-to-stop-windows-explorer-from-prepending-http-to-unknown-names-in-address-ba)

Comment: @techie007 I'm not sure how you found that question, but I agree.  Definitely duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't turn it off.

But you can enter command prompt by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and typing `cmd`.

There it doesn't open a website if you type it, just an error message.

Comment: The only problem with Windows + R is that it doesn't open cmd in the current working directory.  If you can provide a link that says it can't be turned off, I'll accept this answer.  Also, +1.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer so you see it uses/is the WindowsShell which has a built-in function to open urls (the same which is used by the Internet Explorer) - Maybe it works if you uninstall Internet Explorer and use Chrome or Firefox (but no garantie on proper working Windows without IE)

Comment: I don't know an answer, but I don't think it's impossible. Maybe some registry settings could do it?

Comment: `The only problem with Windows + R is that it doesn't open cmd in the current working directory.` That’s hardly the “only” problem. The `Win+R→cmd` “solution” only applies to this specific use-case scenario. What happens when you try to enter a file or folder name in the address bar and end up doing a search for the path and folder name (and possibly end up leaking your handle or even full name to the Internet)? How does `Win+R` help with that?

Answer (score 2):

The only settings I can find will disable "Searching", but still open up Internet Explorer with a site that says the URL cannot be found :-/

Instead, Hold Shift on your keyboard and Right Click in the directory you wish to Open the command prompt from: Select "Open Command Window Here" from the Context menu...
This works in Windows 7.